# Can I stop Apache2 server with Caddy in docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apache2, caddy

I'm running a container with Caddy. My website is properly working. I can access it.

The problem is that whenever I visit any page on my website - I can see `apache2` that takes a lot of CPU (in `top`). Can I safely stop & delete apache service since I'm already running Caddy in docker?

I was trying to run:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

But it says that

```
Failed to stop apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not loaded.
```

In `top` I can see that the process is being run by user `www-data`.